# Using django tags inside angular 4 templates?

Tags: python, django, angular

I have a web server in `Django` and `Angular 4` frontend, but my problem is that I can't use tags Django in templates angular.

E.g.

I have this index.html like root in /templates (django)

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TrackerFrontend</title>
    <base href="{% static %}">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link
         rel="stylesheet"
         type="text/css"
         href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fontin">
     Not work
       -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'inline.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polyfills.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'styles.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vendor.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.bundle.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I try call a media file from my server I can see this

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}/images/2017-08-12-19-28-20st1folio1.png">
```

But when I copy and paste the same img tag, do `npm run build` in my project angular and run again my server, I receive errors in terminal

```
Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)
```

this index.html is a copy of the real in frontend app, but I add `{% load static %}` and others tags to call `bundle.js` files.

It's possible replicate that call `{% load static %}` inside of each angular component?

The same error appears without the need to do `npm run build`

Answer (score 1):

Change
    `<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}/images/2017-08-12-19-28-20st1folio1.png">`
to `<img src="{{ get_media_prefix }}/images/2017-08-12-19-28-20st1folio1.png">`

Comment: Not work bro, I change these and not show media_root like index.html